# matplotlib.pyplot.scatter is not working consistently while plotting in python 3.8

Tags: python, matplotlib, signal-processing

The `matplotlib.pyplot.scatter` is not working consistently while plotting the data set in python 3.8 as some of the intermediate data points were not connecting in random intervals and some of the data points were connected.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def _plot_time_data(data):

    num_plots = 1
    fig, subplot = plt.subplots(num_plots, figsize=(30, num_plots*80), squeeze=False, tight_layout=True)           
    x = 0
    y = 0

    subplot[x][y].scatter(data["t"], data["value"],zorder=1)
    subplot[x][y].set_title("time vs data,",fontsize=15, fontweight='bold')
    subplot[x][y].set_xlabel("Time in seconds")
    subplot[x][y].set_ylabel("(-)L   PhaseShift[us]   R(+)",fontsize=15,fontweight='bold')
    subplot[x][y].plot(data["t"], data["value"], '.r-',scalex=True, scaley=True, zorder=2)
    subplot[x][y].margins(0)
    yl_lmt = (min(data["value"]) - abs(min(data["value"]))/2) if (min(data["value"]) - abs(min(data["value"]))/2) !=0 else -1
    yh_lmt = (max(data["value"]) + abs(max(data["value"]))/2) if (max(data["value"]) + abs(max(data["value"]))/2) !=0 else  1
    subplot[x][y].set_ylim(yl_lmt, yh_lmt)
    subplot[x][y].set_xlim(xStart, xStop)
    subplot[x][y].grid(linestyle='dotted', color='grey')
```

Below is the plot where scatter connects some of the data points and not all.

[image]

Comment: You have `nan`s in your data.

Comment: Thanks for input and let me check that and will update here

Comment: numpy.isnan(data).any() returns False as data set does not have any nump.nan and i checked with for loop as well as no nan present in the data set

Comment: Please include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Without the data it is extremely difficult to figure out what might be wrong.

Comment: sure i can attach the data but it's quite a big size and not sure how to attach it

Comment: That's strange, I only know of nans being able to cause jumps in a line plot. @VJA You don't need to attach all the data, just 5 point before and after the first jump for example.

Comment: 1. 9.69683648222030000000,
2. 9.68638392784271000000,
3. 9.67706508436805000000,
4. 9.66995660700575000000,
5. 9.66678874547710000000,
6. 9.66107607247579000000,
7. 9.65713880063390000000 <--graph ending,
------->disconnect between previous and next graph data points,
8. 9.9590740951782600000 <-- graph start, 
9. 8.4954016479343800000,
10. 8.0604577128440200000,
11. 7.4022415539332000000,
12. 7.0653436825551800000,
13. 6.9678272254236600000,
14. 6.7719832319568200000,
15. 6.6122714761362900000,

Comment: Please add this as an edit to the question in a format that we can easily use to test ourselves.